# Updating progressBar using threads and delegate method with arguments in C++/CLI using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have this code in my Managed C++/Cli in Visual Studio 2022, I want to update the progressBar value in different stages of my c++ function. So far I have 3 delegates **UpdateUi()**, **UpdateUiDone()** and **UpdateProgress(int percent)** which passes an int percent as an argument. These delegates have the methods **UiDoSome()**, **UiDosomeDone()** and **UpdateProgressBar(int percent)**. How this code runs is that on a click of a button, a new thread starts which calls the function **ThreadProc**. SPP is the name of the windows form class. Here is my code:

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
      Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &SPP::ThreadProc));
      t->Start();
}
```

ThreadProc function:

```
public: System::Void ThreadProc() {

     label6->Invoke(gcnew UpdateUi(this, &SPP::UiDoSome));
  -> progressBar1->Invoke(gcnew UpdateProgress(this, &SPP::UpdateProgressBar(25)));

       //My code goes in here......

     label6->Invoke(gcnew UpdateUiDone(this, &SPP::UiDosomeDone));
}
```

Delegates definition:

```
public: delegate void UpdateUi();
public: delegate void UpdateUiDone();
public: delegate void UpdateProgress(int percent);
```

Delegates' methods:

```
public: void UiDoSome() {
    label6->Text = "processing...";
}
public: void UiDosomeDone() {
    label6->Text = "Done!!!";
}
public: void UpdateProgressBar(int percent) {
    progressBar1->Value = percent;
}
```

The problem is that , when invoking the progressBar in the **ThreadProc** function and I pass a value to the **UpdateProgressBar** method, the compiler throws an error: "expression must be an lvalue or a function designator". How can I solve this, is this even possible in C++? I know C# has no such issues. I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wants a function *name*, not the function return value.  And gets upset when the function returns void. 
 Write Invoke(gcnew UpdateProgress(this, &MyForm::UpdateProgressBar), 25) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an array to pass arguments when using Invoke(), like this:

```
array<System::Object^>^ params = gcnew array<System::Object^>(1);
params[0] = 25;
Invoke(gcnew UpdateProgress(this, &SPP::UpdateProgressBar), params);
```

But, you cannot use Invoke() in the first place, since UI elements (buttons, labels etc) can be safely modified only from the thread they were created by. Therefore, you have to use BeginInvoke() here. Also, you can use BeginInvoke of the form itself:

```
public: System::Void ThreadProc() {

    BeginInvoke(gcnew UpdateUi(this, &SPP::UiDoSome));

    array<System::Object^>^ params = gcnew array<System::Object^>(1);
    params[0] = 25;
    BeginInvoke(gcnew UpdateProgress(this, &SPP::UpdateProgressBar), params);

    BeginInvoke(gcnew UpdateUiDone(this, &SPP::UiDosomeDone));
}
```

Comment: Hans Passant answer is correct. Thanks Hans

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, too. Both responses are correct (I tested it). Anyway, please, also take a look at BeginInvoke part of the response - you really can't update UI elements (controls) from non-UI thread. Or, more precisely, you can update them only from the thread you created them in. If you do so, there is a good chance that the app would crash randomly in the future. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: Thanks Jiri for your input as well. Will consider that.